# How to make a Drupal Main Menu Dynamic?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

First, excuse my english! ;)

I need change the link of main menu, according to the url.

In front page, need a menu,with their links, and for example in `"/content/%"` other menu. I know to change all page, only changing "Show block on specific pages", but main menu does not appear in block.

More info:

I have a content type with 8000 entries, all towns in Spain. The page name is towns.com for example, if i go to towns.com, would have to see a page format with their blocks. If i go to my town page(content), would have to see changed all the page.

I read about the subdomain module, for put a subdomain for all of towns, if this solves my problem, this is best! I prefer see the towns in subdomain, but this is a big problem, I am content without subdomains ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module page with dynamic path.